# ace:chart how to set xAxis tick with AxisType:DATE

Tags: java, jsf, charts, icefaces

I have this code but I don't know how to complete formatString and TickInterval field

```
    xAxis.setAutoscale(Boolean.TRUE);
    xAxis.setType(AxisType.DATE);
    xAxis.setFormatString(???????);  //HH:mm:ss
    xAxis.setTickInterval("???? 1 minute");  //every minute
```

I need to have on x axis the time minute by minute. 
I use the ace:chart component.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I did it by myself.

Hope this can be useful:

```
    xAxis.setAutoscale(Boolean.TRUE);
    xAxis.setType(AxisType.DATE);
    xAxis.setFormatString("%T");
    xAxis.setTickInterval("1 minute");
```